# Is it possible to COPY tables into PostgreSQL without setting structure first?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, table

I'm just getting to grips with PostgreSQL 9.6.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to add a .csv table to a database without first creating the table structure in `psql` or pgAdmin?

Or...I've not used scripts before but if someone could suggest one and give me a quick run through, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: read this first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table , some information could be useful

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature in pgAdmin (but then I don't use pgAdmin) The SQL client that I am using has a special command to detect the structure from the file: http://sql-workbench.net/manual/script-generation.html#command-gen-imptable and suggest a corresponding DDL statement.

Comment: Use 3rd-party tools, there's nothing bundled.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's good to know that I'm not missing a built in feature.

Comment: csvkit is your friend here

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with all columns being text and if the CSV file has at least a header line with column names, then one ugly solution could be:

Create a table with a single column. Then import the first row of the CSV file into that table. You can then get a list of the names and generate a CREATE TABLE statement from that.

Something like:

```
create table header_names (header_line text);
```

Then import the first row into that table.

Something like (untested!):

```
\copy header_names from (program 'head -n 1 data.txt')
```

`\copy` and `COPY` do not have a way of limiting the number of rows that are imported, so you need to use `head` to just get the first line.

Then use:

```
select 'create table import ('||string_agg(col_name||' text', ', ')||');'
from header_names
   cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(header_line,',')) as x(col_name);
```

The second parameter to the `string_to_array()` function is the delimiter of your CSV file.

Assuming you have a header like:

```
id,first_name,last_name
```

The above will generate:

```
create table import (id text, first_name text, last_name text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I always like an ugly workaround. For some tables this could work well I think.

Answer (score -2):

CSV does not contain data type information, so it's impossible to create the table structure from CSV files.

Comment: While true, good tools can guess pretty well based on the values and propose a table structure for you to tweak.